# Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm running a testing server with XAMPP 1.8.1 with Apache 2.4.3 and PHP 5.4.7 on Windows 7 Home Premium. Everything was working swell yesterday, but today I started receiving this in Apache's error.log:
`Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.`

I can't think of any changes in my code that would have caused the problem, and I haven't changed any Apache settings in quite some time. I've tried other searches that deal with status 3221225477, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything with the different error code.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Comment: Status `3221226356` is `0xC0000374` in Hex, and it indicates a heap correction (`STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`). Some other programs like Google Drive may be interfering. Switching to the latest version of Apache (XAMPP) *may* fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039562/parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221226356-restarting#comment-26309445) by [Amal Murali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438393/amal-murali), upgrading XAMPP solved the issue. Don't know if it deleted a bad file or added a good one, but it worked!

Comment: Glad to know that helped. You should accept your answer by clicking on the green checkmark, then :-)