# can setInterval cause apache restarts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

first of all,i'm not pro coder,just teach myself with some code snippets.
play arround with some coding experiments to gain experience

i trie to load php into div which is no problem,but if i set these into intervall
my  Apache 2.4.29 with PHP 7.1.11 crashes with an restarts every 2-4 hours

my code could cause that?

error log:

> [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6712:tid 724] AH00428: Parent: child process 7468 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.

my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){                   
    $(\'#der_winner\').load("'.MYURL.'module/jackpotwinner.php");
  }, 1000);
});
```

and php:

```
$slotplayer_s = $Router->mysqlcnt("SELECT name FROM status WHERE show = '2'",1);
            echo "".$slotplayer_s."";
```

i updated xampp to newest version,
copy/pasted some dll between apache and php,
played arround with php.ini and some values and times
nothing helped
I do not understand why that happens,any teaching or suggestions are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039562/parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221226356-restarting)

Comment: @dferenc I don't think it's really a duplicate, since they are asking a very specific and different question, but the answer probably will still help them.

Comment: tried this before posting,latest version of xampp installed,but still have the restart. but noticed that i've no php5apache2_4.dll in my php (7.1.11) folder. is this not longer used in php 7+?

Comment: If a set interval can cause it, so can constantly refreshing the page on that endpoint. the setInterval, javascript, and jquery are mostly irrelevant.

Comment: There is a thread on [apachelounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=34002) about this. (Without solution though, and not sure if it's relevant for you.)

Comment: thx @dferenc ,i just try to copy some newer dated  dll into apache folder

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are somehow DDoSing yourself with the `setInterval` by calling it too often (which I wouldn't think a 1s interval, even with lots of users) could cause.

As dferenc linked, check out this answer: [Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039562/parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221226356-restarting)

Comment: Anyone care to comment why the downvote? I answered the question.

Comment: Just to let you know, it was not me.

Comment: i don`t also downvote this.thx for suggestion but always updated to latest xampp

Comment: after messing arround with that, i decided to deinstall xampp with php 7.1.11
and try same with php 5.6.32.

the result : No apache restarts more. now stable since over 10h

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things to get rid of these restarts on latest xampp 
(Nov 10 
Updated PHP to 7.1.11 / 7.0.25 / 5.6.32
Updated Apache to 2.4.29
Updated OpenSSL to 1.0.2m).
but nothing helped me on php 7.1.11.
i deinstalled this version and installed the php 5.6.32.
result is that i have no more restarts,even if i set more requests into interval.

I'm not really happy with it,but i was unable to solve the problem with php 7.1.11
If a correct solution for php 7.1.11 can still be found, I would be very happy
thx for help so long